# Failed getting release file while running debootstrap with sudo

Tags: sudo, proxy, debootstrap

If I run `debootstrap in` with `sudo` I get the following output:

```
I: Retrieving InRelease 
I: Failed to retrieve InRelease
I: Retrieving Release 
E: Failed getting release file http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/Release
```

If I run the command directly as root, all seems well and the chroot will be built perfectly.

On my local machine I'm also able to build the chroot with `sudo`. The difference is the configured proxy. I guess that `debootstrap` doesn't use the proxy if I run it with `sudo`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sudo` sets up only a limited environment and you might for instance miss the `http_proxy` env variable that gets initiated by your login shell.
You might try to run sudo with the `-i` option as that will simulate a login session which might load a more complete environment that includes proxy settings or modify `/etc/sudoers` to stop suppressing the proxy environment vars with :

```
 #/etc/sudoers
 Defaults env_keep += "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"
```