# Mirror download fails with error: Failed getting release file while running debootstrap with sudo

Tags: ubuntu, chroot, debootstrap, schroot

I run the command

```
$ sudo debootstrap --variant=buildd --arch i386 lucid /var/chroot/ https://mirror.internet.asn.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/
```

and the error is:

```
I: Retrieving InRelease 
I: Retrieving Release 
E: Failed getting release file https://mirror.internet.asn.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/lucid/Release
```

I've tried with other mirrors too. I've also read the [similar issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334303/failed-getting-release-file-while-running-debootstrap-with-sudo), but I don't understand the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [distribution index](https://mirror.internet.asn.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/) on your mirror, you’ll see that `lucid` isn’t available. In fact it’s long gone from the main mirrors; you’ll need to use [the archive](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/):

```
sudo debootstrap --variant=buildd --arch i386 lucid /var/chroot/ http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

(I assume you have your reasons for wanting to set up a chroot with a 13-year-old version of Ubuntu!)

Comment: Thank you. No reason for an old version, I just need a clean version of virt-manager on a USB for an offline install. I was following this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot

Comment: I just don't know what command to run so my Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS jammy Desktop can run chroot? The Ubuntu guide is confusing with the lucid thingy? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebootstrapChroot

Comment: Fixed with command: sudo debootstrap jammy jammy