# Failed getting release file while running debootstrap with root privileges

Tags: ubuntu, chroot, debootstrap

I've tried to install chroot using debootstrap with root account and receive same error everytimes.

```
Using debootstrap from /usr/sbin/debootstrap
Running debootstrap to install base system, this may take a while...
I: Retrieving InRelease 
I: Retrieving Release 
E: Failed getting release file http://mirror.kakao.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/Release
```

below is my running code.

```
debootstrap --variant=minbase --arch amd64 focal /chroot/domjudge http://mirror.kakao.com/ubuntu
```

I checked the similar question [#1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334303/failed-getting-release-file-while-running-debootstrap-with-sudo), [#2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/757288/mirror-download-fails-with-error-failed-getting-release-file-while-running-debo?newreg=f53e0031d7274277b69849cbc8a077e3), but none of them could solve my issue. what should I do for running this code?